# Wrong value returning from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I'm working with a GridView, e, populated by a SQL Server stored procedure.
When trying to extract a specific cell value from the GV, my code is returning the wrong value and type; I can't figure out why:

```
String itemSummary = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;
String itemTotal = e.Row.Cells[8].Text;
```

Although the data in the database table is type double 18,2 and the sproc is retrieving the data and populating the GV successfully, when I go to extract the itemSummary, the code is returning "Cn". itemTotal, extracted in exactly the same way, is returning as expected. Looking at the GridView, I can't even see where "Cn" would have originated.

When I step through the code using breakpoints, I can drill down into the Row's ItemArray and clearly see the expected value at row index [4] but `e.Row.Cells[4].Text` still returns string "Cn".

Again `e.Row.Cells[8].Text` returns the same value as represented by row index [8] in the row's ItemArray as expected.

I need help with this; any ideas would be much appreciated..

Comment: Try retrieving the value using column name so you're sure it's getting exactly what you want.

Comment: In which event are you trying to access the values? If you are using `TemplateField` instead of `BoundField` then use `FindControl` method to find the respective control declared in the `ItemTemplate` and try accessing the `Text` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field that was returning the incorrect value was formatted as currency. As it turned out, the formatting had been applied both in the markup and the code behind; this appears to have caused the problem. Once the formatting had been removed from the markup, problem solved..

Answer (score 1):

I'd try printing out the whole table to see which values are returned. A loop for the cells inside a loop for the rows should make it much more visible to you what is happening. Remember to put spacings in front of the printing values and \n at the end of a row.

Good luck!